# Why this java compile Error happens? "java: unreported exception X; must be caught or declared to be thrown"

Tags: java, java-8

I have a this very simple line of code that is not compiling on 1.8.0_74

```
Collections.singleton(Optional.of("").orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new));
```

Compiler error is:

`Collections.singleton(Optional.of("").orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new));
                                                  ^
  where X,T are type-variables:
    X extends Throwable declared in method orElseThrow(Supplier)
    T extends Object declared in class Optional`

On the other hand it compiles fine when you break it to separate lines:

```
String some = Optional.of("").orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
Collections.singleton(some);
```

Comment: Does this work by any chance?
ImmutableSet.of(Optional.of(new String()).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException())).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException());

I have a feeling it's complaining as you're not throwing the exception up the chain, that's an example, though I'm sure there are better ways to pass the exception on then what I've done

Comment: What happens if you make the first version `Optional.<String>of(new String())...`?

Comment: @Draken nope in your proposed code is wrong. The method `orElseThrow()` returns the specific type `String` and it's being set of one element of `String` in this case, so you can't do again `orElseThrow()` on the set object.

Comment: @chrylis nope this type hint doesn't help and it's still not compiling.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523375/java8-lambdas-and-exceptions

Comment: Yes @chrylis this looks like my question is a duplicate then. Sadly that they put resolve on java 9... Anyway I will download pre release and see what comes out. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, it will be [backported to 8u92](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8142883).

Comment: I do confirm this is compiling fine on **jdk-9-ea+111**

Comment: Nice (almost) self-contained example. You could get rid of the 3rd party library reference by replacing `ImmutableSet.of` with `Collections.singleton`. And you can simplify the example by replacing `new String()` with `""` and `() -> new RuntimeException()` with `RuntimeException::new`…

Comment: Thanks @Holger that was a good catch

Comment: Another interesting fact related to this issue is that eclipse (4.5.2) internal compiler compiles this code smoothly :-)

Comment: I've just checked with lately released 8u92 and I do confirm it works fine now !