# maven-compiler-plugin fails to compile a file that Eclipse has no problem with

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

Eclipse compiles the following code without any problem, whereas when `mvn` tries to compile this code, a compilation failure results:

```
try {
    // Distribution.rep().get(id) returns a java.util.Optional
    Distribution updated = Distribution.rep().transact(() -> {
        Distribution distro = Distribution.rep().get(id).orElseThrow(() -> {
            throw new NotFoundException("Couldn't find Distribution with ID '%s'.", id);
        });
        // Other stuff...
    });
    rs.setData(updated);
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // Handle the error
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle the exception
}
```

The error thrown by `maven-compiler-plugin:3.1` is:

```
unreported exception java.lang.Throwable; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

`NotFoundException extends RuntimeException`. The `transact` method wraps all runtime (?) exceptions in an `ExecutionException` before throwing them. Either way, this `NotFoundException` (when thrown) should get caught by the `catch` clause for `ExecutionException`, so what's the problem?

From what I can understand the `maven-compiler-plugin` seems to think that the `NotFoundException` is a `Throwable`. `NotFoundException` is defined in my code (project), so `maven-compiler-plugin`should know about it...

Source and target for the compiler plugin are defined as `1.8`. Have Java version `1.8.0_181`. Tried with `maven-compiler-plugin` version `3.8.0`, got the same result.

Comment: Eclipse uses its' own compiler. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler

Comment: Seems to me that the code should compile with any compiler...

Comment: `RuntimeException` makes it an *unchecked* exception. As for why eclipse allows it; it might be a corner case in the language spec (or it could be an eclipse [bug](https://i.redd.it/b44yvqgindh01.jpg)).

Comment: Exactly, `RuntimeException` is an unchecked exception. Then why am I getting an error saying that I need to either catch it (which I am doing) or declare it in a throws clause. Neither of the questions you've pointed out solve my problem. This is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: Or, it could be a [javac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25533461/2970947) bug.

Comment: Maybe it is not the `NotFoundException` but something else that is causing the error. Did you try to remove it?

Comment: I could solve the issue by supplying a type parameter to `orElseThrow()`: `Distribution.rep().get(id).<NotFoundException>orElseThrow(...` etc. If this question were not marked as duplicate I would be able to add this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Henry Yes I have checked that it is the `NotFoundException` that is causing the issue. See my previous comment for how I was able to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Henry I would be helpful if you voted to reopen the question.

Comment: Actually it is a duplicate.