# Java8 Stream .orElseThrow unreported exception error

Tags: java, exception, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to track down why a specific behavior is happening with `.orElseThrow` in a Java Stream. This code block

```
private SomeContainer getSomeContainerFromList(SomeContainerList containerList, String containerId) {

   return containerList.stream()
           .filter(specificContainer -> specificContainer.getId().equals(containerId))
           .findAny()
           .orElseThrow(() -> {
               String message = "some special failure message";
               log.error(message);
               throw new CustomInternalException(message)});
}
```

results in this error: **`unreported exception X; must be caught or declared to be thrown`**

I don't want to report the exception because that would cause me to add that to every other method who interacts with this.

However, when I remove the curly braced lambda expression, leaving just the new exception to be thrown, like so:

```
private SomeContainer getSomeContainerFromList(SomeContainerList containerList, String containerId) {

   return containerList.stream()
           .filter(specificContainer -> specificContainer.getId().equals(containerId))
           .findAny()
           .orElseThrow(() -> new CustomInternalException("some special failure message"));
}
```

It compiles just fine and the exception no longer needs to be reported, although, I can't log the message or do any other logic in that `.orElseThrow` statement.

Why does this happen? I've seen a sort of [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523375/java8-lambdas-and-exceptions) which explains that this could be a bug in the JDK but I want to make sure that is the case in my situation.

Comment: under `java-8` tag, read [two questions back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60118056/the-method-mapfunction-super-role-extends-r-in-the-type-streamrole-is-n)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don’t *throw* the exception, *return* it:

```
.orElseThrow(() -> {
    String message = "some special failure message";
    log.error(message);
    // change “throw” to “return”:
    return new CustomInternalException(message)});
```

[`.orElseThrow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier)) accepts a `Supplier<Exception>`, which should *return*, rather than *throw*, an exception.

Comment: Oh thanks, my mistake I'll edit that. Its actually supposed to say throw.

Comment: @Zach that’s the problem. The lambda is supposed to be a *Producer* of Exception, of not *throw* one.

Comment: @Bohhemian, I see, so now with a returned exception I need to catch it when the method is called?

Comment: @Zach if nothing in the stream matches your filter, your lambda will be called and its returned exception thrown. If `CustomInternalException` is not a `RuntimeException` you must catch it or declare the calling method as `throws CustomInternalException`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
.orElseThrow(() -> {
    String message = "some special failure message";
    log.error(message);
    // change “throw” to “return”:
    new CustomInternalException(message)});
```

You don`t want throw keyword inside` orElseThrow`