# Java Optional orElseThrow compilation error after upgrading to AGP 4.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

The following code used to compile fine:

```
optional.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Could not create stuff"))
```

After upgrading to Android Gradle plugin 4.1 it no longer compiles me in android studio:

I followed the answer here:

[Java8 Lambdas and Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523375/java8-lambdas-and-exceptions)

```
optional.<RuntimeException>orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Could not create stuff"))
```

but still it does not help me.

The build.gradle compiler options are:

```
compileSdkVersion 29

compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

What can be done to solve the issue?

Update: The problem only happens when orElseThrow is in a  constructor.

Comment: what compile time error are you getting?

Comment: error: unreported exception Throwable; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                optional.<RuntimeException>orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Could not create stuff"));